# Problem downloading large files with Rails, Nginx (with x-accel-redirect) and Apache(x-sendfile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, x-sendfile

We have a **big** problem with downloads when the size is over than 1gb.

We are using Rails 2.3.5, passenger 2.2.9 on Amazon EC2 2gb with 2gb of Ram and Fedora 10.

Files are stored on /mnt/files, project is on /mnt/www/project

We tried to send files with Nginx and x-accel-redirect and also Apache with x-sendfile.

We can download only and always **1.09gb** instead of 1.54gb!!

We can download files without problems where size is less than **1gb**

If we link same file (that is not corrupted) in rails public dir, we can download without any problem.

X-Accel-Redirect or X-SendFile are configured correctly, tested and checked a lot of time.

So:

1. Nginx with x-accel-redirect [**fail**]
2. Apache with x-send-file [**fail**]
3. Send File without x-accel-redirect or x-sendfile on nginx or apache [**fail**]
4. Linking file in public and direct download [**works**]

Any suggestion?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to restrict access to these downloads, have you tried the [Access Key module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpAccessKeyModule)?